# Image not showing when trigger liszt:updated

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-chosen

[image: Output]

I'm using [chosenImage](https://github.com/djgrant/chosen-image) plugin. When I trigger `liszt:updated` it won't show images in list.

*Script*

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(".my-select").chosenImage({
    disable_search_threshold: 10 
  });

  // some code that adding/removing options in select

   $('#my-select').trigger('liszt:updated'); 
</script>
```

*HTML*

```
<select class="my-select" id="my-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
  <option data-img-src="chosenImage/flag-red.gif">Project A</option> 
  <option data-img-src="chosenImage/flag-purple.gif">Project B</option> 
</select>
```

Any solutions? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the code in example you do not need `$('#my-select').trigger('liszt:updated');`

Only this should work

```
$(".my-select").chosenImage({
  disable_search_threshold: 10 
});
```

This should work

```
  $('#my-select').trigger('liszt:updated'); 
  $(".my-select").chosenImage();
```

Just call the chosenImage() method after updating list

Comment: But I need to update the chosen list after some operations like appending other options and 'Add new' Options on button click etc.